# Performing calculations on data via json

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to perform a simple addition on data I have gathered from an external source via JSON.  The data I am getting is being returned as a string but is a number so I have tried using both parseInt() and Number() to no avail.  I have shown a simple section of the code below:

```
 var total_energy = 0;
 var energy_val;

$.each(result.report.food.nutrients, function (i, v) {

if (v.name == "Energy"){

                     energy_val = v.value;

                     var energy = Number(energy_val);

                     total_energy = total_energy + energy;




                                          console.log("energy " + energy);
                                          console.log("totalenergy " + total_energy);
                                          energy_val = "";
                                          energy = 0;

  }
   }
```

The console returns the correct value for energy each time but the totalenergy value just seems to stay the same as the energy value.  The sum doesn't seem to have any affect. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

change `console.log("energy " + total_energy);` to `console.log("energy " + energy);`

Comment: thanks, silly mistake. the values still remain the same though

Comment: @NeilKennedy how your console output looks like?

Comment: for example, it will be energy 106, total energy 106.  This is the correct energy value, but when i click another value it will change both numbers to for example energy 100, total energy 100 rather than energy 100, total energy 206

Comment: I suppose that when you click, `var total_energy = 0;` runs. Check it out.

Comment: what do u mean by click another value? Doing so, does the clicked item get added to `result.report.food.nutrients`?? If not then, the observation that you get is correct as the `total_energy` variable is global.

Comment: @madox2 var total_energy = 0; is defined outside the click event and is initialised as 0 but shouldn't reset with the click

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary This is inside a click event which runs at ajax request, this is just the basic code I have shown. the clicked item gets added to a list but I'm just using the console at the minute for testing purposes

Comment: @NeilKennedy with these informations all I can advise you is to debug your code (e.g. console.log) and focus on all places where you initialize/reassign `total_energy` variable

Answer (score 0):

try parseInt your values... can be this

Comment: just try to change the number() to parseInt()? I tried this but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if its due to the closure created in the loop where you are iterating over the items. Try the following code.

```
 var total_energy = 0;
 var energy_val;

$.each(result.report.food.nutrients, function (i, v) {
        var item = v;
       //Calling calculateEnergy() function so that each 'item' is the current instance 'v'  value.
       (function calculateEnergy(itemClicked))(item);
   }

function calculateEnergy(itemClicked){
   if(itemClicked.name == "Energy"){
                     energy_val = itemClicked.value;
                     var energy = Number(energy_val);

                     total_energy = total_energy + energy;
                     console.log("energy " + energy);
                     console.log("totalenergy " + total_energy);
                     energy_val = "";
                     energy = 0;
        }
}
```

I have put comments within the code.

**Update** console.log() is buggy with ajax requests. So instead of logging, try creating an html div and populate the values there.